# Letter of recommendation from professors without prior contact

Tags: application, recommendation-letter

I am a postdoctoral researcher at a German university and aim to apply for a visiting lecturer program to be a visiting professor at a foreign university. For this, I am required to provide two reference letters from two professors working at German universities but not at my university. As most of my collaborators are either from my university or from international institutions, the options are pretty limited for me.

Isn't it silly to request such a letter from a professor without prior direct contact? If yes, how am I supposed to fulfil this condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is silly. Boneheaded, actually. I assume that they don't want many applicants and I wouldn't put a lot of hopes on this position.

But you might ask some of your current colleagues for advice. It might be that your work has been shared with other German scholars who might be able to provide a (mild) recommendation based on your published work.

You could also ask for an exception, explaining your situation. Some other arrangement might be made to happen if you, otherwise, seem like a good candidate.

Good luck and keep looking.

Comment: Ask your PI if they have any German peers who might provide a recommendation based on your PI's recommendation to them.  It's not the way to get high fidelity recommendations; but, this request sounds more like it is biased to select a person with a German network of peers, so give it to them :)

Answer (score 4):

Silly or not, these are the written requirements. The issue of course is that you don't have two people who can write with actual knowledge of your work.

Write to the chair of the search committee and ask them for an exception and that you can provide references from researchers abroad.

Answer (score 2):

Letters from faculty at universities who the candidate has not worked with is often part of a tenure promotion package. Requesting such letters is usually an attempt to obtain an external opinion of your research. The idea is that people you have collaborated with are likely to write positive letters about you, so someone who is detached from your work can only represent their views of the merits of your research.

The search committee here may have that same goal in mind.

Comment: So you mean it is a kind of a review (FYI they call it a reference letter)? The question again is whether it is common to request such a letter without prior contact?

Comment: I don't know about this search specifically, but I wanted to state one possible reason for such a letter. It could be called a "review" or "reference letter." For tenure promotion packages, such reviewers are usually referred to as "letter writers."